# Java environment broken?

Tags: java, pdfsam

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10. Two packages which I'd like to use won't start up. First is pdfsam. Starting from terminal I get the following output:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/layout/HBox
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.pdfsam.community.App.main(App.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.layout.HBox
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
```

Second one is mediathekview. Here the output is as follows:

```
Fehler: Hauptklasse mediathek.Main kann nicht initialisiert werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jidesoft/utils/ThreadCheckingRepaintManager
```

I had purged and reinstalled both packages and java components, but still fails.

Any ideas please how to fix this?

Kind regards

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Java 8 (openjdk-8-jre or your repository's equivalent package) and openjfx. Then select openjdk-8 as the default Java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This was an issue with Java 9 and 10 noted on the [PDFSAM website](https://pdfsam.org/open-source/pdfsam-basic-not-starting-on-ubuntu/1938/).